# Measurement error

Tags: error, measurement

Assume $K=1$, no intercept and both $y$ and $x$ are observed with error 
$$
y = \hat{y}+v
$$ 
and 
$$
x=\hat{x}+u
$$ 
where $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ denote the true value and 
$$
E[v] = E[u] = 0
$$
and 
$$
E[vv']=\sigma^2*I_t
$$

Then 
$$
p_{{\rm lim}}(b-\beta) = -\beta  \frac{\sigma^2_u}{\sigma^2_x} \neq 0
$$

How do derive the above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must clearly be related to the fact that we estimate:
$$y-v=(x - u)\beta + \epsilon$$ Therefore you just have to calculate the estimator $\hat{\beta}$ of the equation $$y=x\beta + \eta, $$ where $$\eta=-u\beta+v+\epsilon.$$ As the OLS estimator is applied to the variables with measurement error we have $$ \hat{\beta}=(x'x)^{-1}x'y=(x'x)^{-1}x'(x\beta + \eta)=\beta+(x'x)^{-1}x'\eta.$$

Since $x=\hat{x}+u$ and $\eta=-u\beta+v+\epsilon$ it holds $plim[n^{-1}x'\eta]=-\beta \sigma^2_u$, Additionally we have $plim[n^{-1}x'x]^{-1}=\sigma^{-2}_x$. q.e.d